# GNOME 3.22 - Disable F1 Help Key

Tags: arch-linux, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard, gnome3, guake

Ever since upgrading to GNOME 3.22, there doesn't seem to be any way to disable the F1 Help Center when I'm focused on any GNOME tool (Nautilus, regular desktop, gedit, etc). I have guake set to expand via F1 right now, so you might understand why I'm super annoyed.

I've been through the updated keyboards shortcuts page and neither F1 nor anything that looks like "help center" is on there, and I'm ot really sure what parts of dconf or gsettings would be helpful.

Is there anything I can do?

My system is Arch Linux (updated as far as pacman -Syu will let me).

Comment: F1 is default for the help screen/pages of many apps; the F12 default of guake makes much more sense